# QWebview: How to detect flash video completion?

Tags: flash, qt, pyqt, qwebview

I am attempting to write a program that can play a list of flashes (for example, from YouTube.) I’m using QWebview to show videos, the plugin works fine.

However, how can I tell when a video finishes, so that I can start the next one?

Anyway, are there any other methods to play a list of flash video?

Comment: You need to somehow communicate from your web page (e.g. flash player) into your application. This are distinct environments. Probably, you need to write some javascript or flash. Simplest way, probably, would be to trigger redirect when video is finished playing.

Comment: do you have access to the ActionScript code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I haven't done it yet, but I will try using javascript and see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can, In flash you could check the "meta data", this will have the properties in the flv video, From length of video, audio, cue points etc, also you could check the buffer and compare its percentage: onCompletion handler play next video....

Your best bid would be to check out tutorials on META DATA FLASH PLAYER..theres heaps of different samples around...